# What is the most elegant way to get a subarray from a NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsarray

In Python I can get a subarray easily like this

```
>> v1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>> v2 = v1[1:]
>> v2
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

How can I do the equivalent in Objective-C elegantly?

At first I though this method would do the job:

```
- (void)getObjects:(id[])aBuffer range:(NSRange)aRange
```

But it copies objects to a buffer location. I will need to add them back to another instance of `NSArray`. In addition, the compiler complaints about retain/release properties, which I am really not comfortable  to deal with.

```
    id* objs;

    NSRange rng = NSMakeRange(1, [v1 count] - 1);

    [v1 getObjects:objs range:rng]; # Sending '__strong id *' 
                                    # to parameter of type '__unsafe_unretained id *'  
                                    # changes retain/release properties of pointer
```

So, is there any more elegant way? Or there is no other way but to iterate through `objectEnumerator`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSArray* v1 = @[@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d"];
NSRange rng = NSMakeRange(1,[v1 count]-1);
NSArray* v2 = [v1 subarrayWithRange:rng];
```